# How to use JQuery to call a servlet

Tags: jquery, servlets

How to use JQuery to call a servlet which I usually call like this http://localhost:8080?a=1&b=2&c=3. I particularly want to find out how to pass URL params.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://localhost:8080',
  data: {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3},
  success: function(response) {
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Earlier today I wrote up [a detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445024/jquery-to-php-and-back-again/3445367#3445367) of using the jquery `$.post()` to interact with php. The jquery side will be exactly the same for a servlet; only the address will differ.

If you'd rather use a get request, or return data that is not in the format of either JSON or a string, you can get info about the different methods possible from [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).